# OpenCV camera resolution

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project with OpenCV. It is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. When i start the camera, and do some visual processing the framerate becomes really low and there is a lot of lag. My question is: Would lowering the camera resolution solve my problem(if yes how do I do it)?

Answer (score 0):

Some visual processing as window searching for object detect can act pretty much fast if you're lowering camera resolution, but it would be less effective cause of informations loss by reducing size.

With those low cpu or no gpu device, you have to choose between speed and efficiency cause the limit it the material.

What kind of visual processing algorithm do you use ? Do you use C++ or python ?

Comment: I use python. I just had an idea. If I got a few low resolution frames and than one high resolution frame I would be able to maintain speed and material resolution. Would this be a good idea?

Comment: ok, you could do something a little bit tricky, you capture your frames in high resolution as you're doing now. You resize the frame to have a full resolution frame and a low resolution frame with https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/  try many resolutions to get the efficient one visual processing with the lowest resolution, then when you got the detections or anything else, resize the objects in original size to draw it on the full resolution frame. 
That's how you should work to get beautiful displays using low process visual processing